# how to set dynamically created where Clause in JPA Criteria Queries,

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

This is my Jpa Query Criteria...

```
EntityManagerFactory em;
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<SearchUser> cq = cb.createQuery(SearchUser.class);
    Root<SearchUser> userRoor = cq.from(SearchUser.class);
    cq.select(userRoot);
    TypedQuery<SearchUser> query = ((EntityManager) em).createQuery(cq);
    List<SearchUser> users = query.getResultList();
```

This is Where Clause i am creating dynamically...now i want the jpa to search result result according to this dynamically generated where clause...but don't know how to append this where clause with select query... can anybody edit and show me right query please... Thanks in Advance

```
StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder();
    whereClause.append("where ")
    if (searchUserDTO.getId() != null) {
        whereClause.append("id=" + searchUserDTO.getId());
        }
        if (searchUserDTO.getFirstName() != null) {
            whereClause.append(" and firstName=" + searchUserDTO.getFirstName());
        }
        if (searchUserDTO.getLastName() != null) {
            whereClause.append(" and lastName=" + searchUserDTO.getLastName());
        }
        if (searchUserDTO.getDateOfBirth() != null) {
            whereClause.append(" and dateOfBirth=" + searchUserDTO.getDateOfBirth());
            }
        if (searchUserDTO.getEmail() != null) {
            whereClause.append(" and email=" + searchUserDTO.getEmail());
        }
```

Comment: muhammad usman, you should post what you have tried.

Comment: I would recommend using Spring Data JPA + QueryDSL for that. Or QueryDSL without Spring Data if not using spring

Comment: Your whereClause is just as string.  Instead of building that string, why not add to the CriteriaQuery directly?  There are plenty of examples showing how to add a where clause: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/Criteria

Comment: Why don't you create your WHERE clause by Criteria Builder?